# Microsoft Graph Client SDK -filter groups by name

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

A rather simple ask but I'm having trouble converting my basic `httpClient` method of querying the Graph into the SDK method. I was using the following and it works fine:

```cs
    var filter = "IT";
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{webOptions.GraphApiUrl}/beta/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName, '{filter}')&$select=id,displayName");
```

...now I'm attempting to filter using the SDK as follows:

```cs
    var groups = await graphServiceClient.Groups
        .Request()
        .Filter($"displayName startswith {filter}")
        .Select("id, displayName")
        .GetAsync();
```

I've also tried `.Filter($"startswith("displayName", {filter}))` and other variants.

I'm getting an `invalid filter clause` error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently it occurs since the provided filter expression for `Filter` method is invalid, it could be validated like this:

```
var message = graphServiceClient.Groups
        .Request()
        .Filter($"displayName startswith '{filter}'")
        .Select("id, displayName").GetHttpRequestMessage();
```

The generated `message.RequestUri` will return the following value:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName startswith '{filter}'&$select=id, displayName}
```

A valid filter expression needs to be specified like this:

```
.Filter($"startswith(displayName, '{filter}')")
```

In case if you want to switch to `beta` version for `GraphServiceClient` class, it could be specified  like this:

```
graphServiceClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";
```

Comment: This would break if {filter} contained an apostrophe, for example, the name "o'brien" essentially making the filter .Filter($"startswith(displayName, 'o'brien')"). -- To many single quotes.

I'm suffering this at the moment where I am filtering based on email address and email can contain an apostrophe.

Comment: Hi Mike, we are also facing this issue, did you happen to find any solution?

Comment: I use this but still get "Invalid filter clause":
var groups = await graphClient.Groups
                                .Request()
                                .Filter($"startswith(displayName, '{groupName}')") 
                                .GetAsync();

Comment: this query works for me.
            usersResultPages = await _graphServiceClient.Users
                            .Request(new Option[] { new QueryOption("$count", "true") })
                            .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                            .Filter($"startswith(displayName, 'j')")
                            .Select("displayName,id,mail")
                            .OrderBy("displayName")
                            .GetAsync();

Comment: The documentation states that single quotes should be escaped with single quotes. So "o'brien" should be escaped to `"o''brien"`