# Microsoft Graph SDK gives 'Invalid filter clause'

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph SDK (C#) to get a group based on its name.

Using this code:

```
var message = graphClient.Groups
                              .Request()
                              .Filter($"startswith(displayName, '#Group 1')");

var request = message.GetHttpRequestMessage().RequestUri;
```

gives a valid URI for the API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName, '#Group 1')
```

Which returns OK in Graph Explorer.

But if I invoke the same request using the SDK like this:

```
var groups = await graphClient.Groups
                              .Request()
                              .Filter($"startswith(displayName, '#Group 1')")
                              .GetAsync();
```

I get the error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: BadRequest Message: Invalid
> filter clause

Why doesn't it work?

According to this question it should work:
[Microsoft Graph Client SDK -filter groups by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660006/microsoft-graph-client-sdk-filter-groups-by-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashtag '#' is causing the error. It can be solved by URL-encoding the group name:

```
string urlEncodedGroupName = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("#Group 1");

var groups2 = await graphClient.Groups
                              .Request()
                              .Filter($"startswith(displayName, '{urlEncodedGroupName}')")
                              .GetAsync();
```